# Jquery: how do I create a thumbnail pager?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I'm looking to create a thumbnail pager just like the one used on msn but not sure what the control or functionality is called. Does anyone have any ideas how to create this?

thanks[image: Here is the control]

Comment: This question is far too broad.  What answers are you you looking to get here?  No one is going to write the code for you... Where exactly are you getting stuck?

Answer (score -1):

There are much of related jquery plugins in Internet http://www.1stwebdesigner.com/css/fresh-jquery-image-gallery-display-solutions/